# while using fscanf in C I am getting wrong result

Tags: c, file

Here I am writing some data to a file and trying to display that data.Is it compulsory to use fscanf before printing that data on the output screen? When I use the fscanf and suppose  I enter the details as:

```
Ram 
usa
12
```

the output comes as

```
Ramusa1212
```

What might be the possible error here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
    FILE *fptr;
    char name[20],address[20];
    int roll;
    fptr=fopen("1.txt","w");
    if(fptr!=NULL){
        printf("file created successfully:you can write into the file now");
        
    }
    else{
        printf("error creating file");
    exit -1;
    }
 printf("enter your name,address,roll number");
 fgets(name,20,stdin);
 scanf("%s",address);
 scanf("%d",&roll);
 fprintf(fptr,"%s%s%d",name,address,roll);
 fclose(fptr);
 fptr=fopen("1.txt","r");
 fscanf(fptr,"%s%s%d",name,address,&roll);
 printf("%s%s%d",name,address,roll);
 fclose(fptr);
 getch();
}
```

Comment: If you're coding in C, do not include the C++ tag.  It is more likely to earn you downvotes than to give you any benefit.

Comment: Do you see any spaces in the format string of ` printf("%s%s%d",name,address,roll);`?  I don't.  Where do you think the spaces will come from?

Comment: I am not complaining about the spaces there!I 12 is being printed twice!!

Comment: You're not checking what `fscanf()` returns.  The seoond one returns 2, not 3.  That's because the `address` now contains `usa12` because there was no spacing.  And `roll` is unchanged because `fscanf()` returned 2.  So it prints the second 12.

Comment: "writing some data to a file" --> post that _exact_ data.

Comment: Make the printing unambiguous when things are going wrong, and check return values.  Consider `printf("[%s][%s][%d]\n", name, address, roll);` — you will see what I mean.  You should always check the return value from input functions — things go wrong very often.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Input `Ram usa 12` and output `Ramusa1212` — as it says in the question.  When I went to edit the question, the information on the input was split over several lines, but without blank lines to make it readily visible.

Comment: thanks sir!!I am new here and I wasnt able to edit the question properly!thanks for help

Comment: what is the solution to this?

Comment: Put spaces between fields when you write the data to the file.  And check that the input functions succeed.  Beware: most addresses contain spaces.